# Error: ORA-06550: line 7, column 21: PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'PROD_ORDERED_FUNC'

Tags: sql

just wanted to ask how to resolve the error above. I am trying to create a function that will generate how many product were ordered per product category.

Here is my function. The function compiled but when I try to run the declare part that's where I get the error.

```
DECLARE
  CURSOR this_category IS 
    SELECT category_id 
    from comm_order_details;
  prod_ordered comm_order_details.quantity%type;
  BEGIN
    For rec_category IN this_category  
      LOOP  
        prod_ordered := prod_ordered_func(rec_category.category_id);
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Category ID:' || rec_category.category_id||'-' ||  'Total Order:' || prod_ordered );
      END LOOP;
   END;
```

Try to run inner queries

Comment: here is the function
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION prod_ordered_func
    (pof_product_name IN comm_order_details.product_name%type,
    pof_product_id IN comm_order_details.product_id%type,
    pof_category_id IN comm_category.category_id%type)
    return NUMBER
    IS prod_ordered comm_order_details.quantity%type;
BEGIN
    SELECT count(quantity) into prod_ordered FROM comm_order_details WHERE category_id = pof_category_id;
    RETURN prod_ordered;
    EXCEPTION
    WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Product ID:' || pof_product_id|| 'NO DATA FOUND');
END;

Comment: Add tag for RDBMS used. Edit question to show formatted code.